# Unable to show Google Earth and native WebGL at the same time in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer-9, webgl, google-earth, internet-explorer-11, x-ua-compatible

I am trying to show Google Earth and native WebGl on the same web page on IE 11.

As I read ([here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/earth/xfCKOhyqJ7Y), [here](https://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=936) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=918) ) there is a known issue whereby GE works properly only when using IE9 compatibilty mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

By the other hand, native WebGL [is only available on IE 11](http://caniuse.com/webgl). So, if I force browser to render IE9 compatibity mode, native WebGL stops working.

Any idea of how to solve this issue?